# return route for exposed docker port behind openvpn-client

Tags: iptables, docker, openvpn, route, nat

I'm trying to reach a docker container, whose outgoing traffic is routed through vpn, over the remote ip of the server where the containers are running on. If i want to reach the squid server from the test environment attached below i have to use a reverse proxy. When i expose the ports on the vpn container without the reverse proxy, my requests are stuck without an answer because of openvpn's route `0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.8.1 dev tun0`:

```
netstat #inside vpn
tcp        0      0 :::3128                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:172.17.0.2:3128  ::ffff:{remote_ip}:49936 SYN_RECV
```

Which rules or routes do i have to add inside the vpn container to have a return route for specific ports via remote ip connections? Can this be achieved by a global rule for all connections coming from the servers remote ip without specifying every single open port? The rules shouldn't interfere with traffic from the attached containers which has to be routed over the vpn.
Thank you so much in advance!

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  vpn:
    container_name: vpn
    image: dperson/openvpn-client
    cap_add:
      - net_admin
    volumes:
      - /dev/net:/dev/net:z
      - ./vpn.ovpn:/vpn/vpn.conf
    dns:
      - 1.1.1.1
    #ports:
    # - "3128:3128"

  vpn_squid:
    image: sameersbn/squid
    volumes:
    - ./squid.conf:/etc/squid/squid.conf
    depends_on:
    - vpn
    network_mode: "service:vpn"

  tcp_proxy:
    container_name: tcp_proxy
    image: tecnativa/tcp-proxy
    environment:
      LISTEN: ":3128"
      TALK: "vpn:3128"
    ports:
      - "3128:3128"

networks:
  default:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ip rule add from 172.22.0.3 lookup 10
ip route add default via 172.22.0.1 table 10
```

This did the trick, where 172.22.0.3 was the IP of the vpn container.
Based on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352841/openvpn-client-and-server-on-same-machine-server-doesnt-allow-connections-whe/352968#352968) answer.